# SQL Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-update, substring

Trying to update column of table from another table but need to modify the values using SUBSTRING. Statements work fine separately but error when combined.

**Working**

```
SET RoomName = DeviceName
```

Before:

| Room Name | Device Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Bldg-Room1-AA |
| B | Bldg-Room2-BA |
| B | Bldg-Room3-BA |
| A | Bldg-Room4-AA |

After:

| Room Name | Device Name |
| --- | --- |
| Bldg-Room1-AA | Bldg-Room1-AA |
| Bldg-Room2-BA | Bldg-Room2-BA |
| Bldg-Room3-BA | Bldg-Room3-BA |
| Bldg-Room4-AA | Bldg-Room4-AA |

---

```
SELECT DeviceName, SUBSTRING(DeviceName,5,LEN(DeviceName)-5)  
FROM Location.Device
```

| Device Name | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Bldg-Room1-AA | Room1-A |
| Bldg-Room2-AA | Room2-A |
| Bldg-Room3-AA | Room3-A |
| Bldg-Room4-AA | Room4-A |

---

**Not Working**

```
SET RoomName = (SELECT DeviceName, SUBSTRING(DeviceName, 5, LEN(DeviceName) - 5) 
                FROM Location.Device)
```

Desired Outcome:

| Room Name | Device Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Room1-A |
| B | Room2-B |
| B | Room3-B |
| A | Room4-A |

Comment: Can you add some sample input/output data here?  Also, if you're using SQL Server specifically, then please add that tag to your question.

Comment: Figured it out:

`SET RoomName = SUBSTRING(DeviceName, 5, LEN(DeviceName) - 5)`

Answer (score 2):

> Only **one expression** can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

```
                       This is one ...     and this is the 2nd expression
                            |                          |
                            v                          v
                       ----------  ---------------------------------------------
SET RoomName = (SELECT DeviceName, SUBSTRING(DeviceName, 5, LEN(DeviceName) - 5) 
                FROM Location.Device)
```

If you're setting `RoomName` to some value (apparently, to `DeviceName`), then remove the 2nd expression from `select`.

Apart from that, pay attention to number of rows returned by subquery; it should return only one row because - if it returns two or more - how will database know *which* value should be put into `RoomName`?

Comment: RoomName is a column, I need to set the values for the entire column. The values I need it set to is the column Device name (via joins [not shown]), but I need the values to be modified with the substring. I hope I'm explaining that correctly.